# How do I get 3 different radio buttons' values in a loop?

Tags: php, loops, get, radio-button

How do I get the values from multiple radio buttons in each row via loop in PHP?

How can I limit the user to select only 3 rows' values?

```
foreach ($course_array as $course_code) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE course_code='$course_code'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $course_title = $row2['course_title'];
    }
    ?>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td><?php echo $count++; ?></td>
        <td>
            <div><?php echo $course_title; ?></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="$count<?php echo $count; ?>" value="1" id="1">1</input>
                <input type="radio" name="$count<?php echo $count; ?>" value="2" id="2">2</input>
                <input type="radio" name="$count<?php echo $count; ?>" value="3" id="3">3</input>
                <input type="radio" name="$count<?php echo $count; ?>" value="4" id="4">4</input>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Your code is not getting any values from radiobuttons. Which three of the four would you want? Also please edit the formatting of your code to make it indent and color properly. Remove the back ticks.

Comment: we don't want to get value from any 3 of these 4 options, we will take only one option from these four. but these are repeated in a loop, like dozens of rows in a single column.We want the user to select maximum of 3 values (means from 3 rows maxuimum)

Comment: surely if you want to select multiple values you want a `<select>` input. if you have it `name="course[]"` then the values will fill `$_POST[course]` with an array

Comment: So there is no way to get value in loop from radio boxes?

Comment: @Shakeeb how about accepting answers to your previous questions before asking new ones? This is not how SO works.